# How to attach debugger with firebase:shell - firestore clould functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

successfully configured firestore cloud functions in local.

able to run the functions locally using below command.

1. firebase functions:shell --port=3535

> firebase var data = require('./data'); wChangedEvent(data.default);

...
...
printing whatever console.log there in wChangedEvent.
So this is working properly.

But i need to attach debugger in visual studio code. I tried with below configuration.

```
   {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 3535,
        "protocol": "inspector"
    },
```

But it is not working.

Comment: The `--port` flag isn't for the node debugger, it's something else.  The best I can tell you is that you can use vscode to look for the process that's used to emulate your function, and each function has its own process.  It's hard to tell them apart.

Comment: How to attach to process in visual studio code?

Comment: Attach to process in visual studio code is not hitting breakpoint

Comment: Maybe this isn't supported yet? I see that [This Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/517) has not been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of late 2020, [this pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/1932) added support for the `--inspect-functions` flag.

```sh
firebase functions:shell --inspect-functions
```

Unless you explicitly provide another, it will open the default node debugger port `9229`.

With Jetbrains IDEs you can attach to the running process by using an ["Attach to Node.js/Chrome" run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html#ws_node_specific_attach_to_chrome_settings).

Comment: In Visual Studio, add a `.vscode/launch.json` with this content:
```{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach Firebase Functions",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: `--inspect-functions` is also available using the emulators: `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions`

Comment: I found that you can't have `--inspect-functions` flag set on emulator session as well as on `functions:shell` session. Corollary: It works when I turned the flag off for emulators, and set it for shell session

Answer (score -1):

You can use the functions emulator. There is ver little documentation, but this is a good start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

```
$ npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator`

$ functions start

$ functions deploy api --trigger-http --timeout 600s

$ functions inspect api --port 9229
```

Create a VS Launce config:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229 
}
```

Now you can F5 to start debugging.

This will **not** receive triggers from your database automatically, but it still very helpful as you can use an http request to trigger functions and debug them.

**Tip**: add this script to your `package.json` so you can easily `npm run debug` to build and deploy to the emulator:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "debug": "npm run build && functions deploy api --trigger-http --timeout 600s && functions inspect api --port 9229"` 
}
```